# Regular expressions for reading sms from device

Tags: c#, regex

I m using the below code to get sms from a mobile deevice. The problem is that it doesn't read null characters, new line (\N) and \r.

```
try
{

    Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d*),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
    Match m = r.Match(input);
    while (m.Success)
    {
        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
        //msg.Index = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
        msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
        msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
        msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
        msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
        msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
        msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
        //string a = msg.Message;
        //string replacement = Regex.Replace(a, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
       // msg.Message = replacement;
        messages.Add(msg);

        m = m.NextMatch();
    }

}
```

For e.g:

if the sms body contains: *"my name is bilal Ahmed"* it will read the above sms

if my sms is: *"my name is \n bilal Ahmed"* it will not read the sms.

For e.g if my sms is: *" "* it will not read the sms.

I think there is some issue in using regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to show us full text which you have in input, but my guess you can try to use something similar to

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d*),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n((.|\r|\n)+)\r\n");
```